# SMPT timeout error with CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

In my local environment the email works, but once I transfer to my online website, the smtp email does not work and shows timeout error.

This is my `config/email.php` file:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed.');

$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = '[email]';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '[password]';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = 30;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
```

I use Cpanel, do I need to configure something?

Comment: Are you using a site hosting provider or your own dedicated/VPS server? It may help to know who your provider is to see if they block the outgoing port 465 for example.

Answer (score 2):

`smtp_host` should change

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = $sender_email;
$config['smtp_pass'] = $sender_password;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

Comment: Should I keep it in the `/config/email.php`? The library is already autoloaded.

Comment: @GabrielMFernandes i didnt get you

Comment: This configuration is located in a file named `email.php` inside of `config` folder, but the line `$this->load->library('email', $config);` you wrote, is it necessary inside of this file? Isn't it used to load libraries directly from the controller, for example?

Comment: No use it in controller. Its seems perfect

Comment: Anyways, still the error `Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection timed out)` :(

Comment: Did you removed `smtp_timeout` ?? make sure two step verification is not enabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102298/discussion-between-gabriel-m-fernandes-and-abdulla).